# Two methods: One defines the values of variables and the other is a constructor that attributes the value to the object

Tags: java

```
 public String toString(){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter 3 digits for your code.");

    int a = keyboard.nextInt();
    int b = keyboard.nextInt();
    int c = keyboard.nextInt();

    String formatcode = "Clockwise " + a + "- Counter-Clockwise " + b + "- Clockwise " + c;

    System.out.println(formatcode);

    keyboard.close();
    return formatcode;
}

CombinationLock(int a, int b, int c){

    num1 = a;
    num2 = b;
    num3 = c;

    open = true;



}
```

I have these two methods but I can't seem to get them to work together in my driver to initialize the variables for my object. It seems weird to have a constructor work after a method but I was asked to do it this way. Any tips or hints are appreciated.

Comment: I haven't seen such code where we are accepting useer input in `toString` method

Comment: toString function are usually not used to asked something from the user. maybe you should ask the three digit in your constructor and don't use argument

Comment: You cannot call a method on an Object before it is initialized with a constructor. What you are trying to do is impossible. Also pelase note that `toString()` is an already existing method of any java Object that you should not override in the way you did.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what I'm asked to do: three parameter constructor - sets the 3 combination numbers to the three passed integers and marks the lock as open. & A toString() method to return the combination of the lock in the following format: Clockwise num1 – Counter-Clockwise num2 – Clockwise num3 where num1, num2 and num3 are the values of the instance variables corresponding to the combination which will open the lock. And with these two ==>  Declare a lock initialize it with a constructor and output the description of the 2 object created. Methods to use: constructors, toString()

Comment: @A.Port The text says that your toString method should **return** the values in a specific String format. It says nothing about that it should set values or ask for input. So yes you did misunderstand the assignment and Ravis answer is actually the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

please do try my answer
this is the main application class

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Driver
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter 3 digits for your code.");

            int a = keyboard.nextInt();
            int b = keyboard.nextInt();
            int c = keyboard.nextInt();
            CombinationLock cl = new CombinationLock(a,b,c);
            System.out.println(cl.toString());
        }


    }
```

this is the CombinationLock class

```
public class CombinationLock
    {
        private int a;
        private int b;
        private int c;

        public CombinationLock(int a,int b,int c)
        {
            this.a=a;
            this.b=b;
            this.c=c;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            String formatcode = "Clockwise " + a  + "- Counter-Clockwise "  + b    + "- Clockwise " + c;
            return formatcode;
       }

    }
```

Comment: this the latest proper formatting because it follows information hiding

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like this ?

```
public String toString(){
    String formatcode = "Clockwise " + this.num1 + "- Counter-Clockwise " + this.num2 + "- Clockwise " + this.num3;

    System.out.println(formatcode);


    return formatcode;
}

CombinationLock(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter 3 digits for your code.");

    int a = keyboard.nextInt();
    int b = keyboard.nextInt();
    int c = keyboard.nextInt();

    this.num1 = a;
    this.num2 = b;
    this.num3 = c;
    keyboard.close();
    this.open = true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by defining a class CombinationLock.

A combination lock has 3 numbers that are required to unlock. These can either 
be passed in when constructing the lock, or are hard coded into the lock. It also contains a method to allow you to unlock it. An implementation could look like this:

```
public class CombinationLock {
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    boolean locked = true;

    public CombinationLock(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
        this.num3 = num3;
    }

    //creates a new combinationlock with default code 1-2-3
    public CombinationLock(){
        this(1,2,3);
    }

   public void unlock(int a, int b, int c){
        if(a==num1 && b==num2 && c==num3){
            locked = false;
        }
    }

    public void lock(){
        locked = true;
    }

    //toString method's are reserved to describe the object as a String.
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String result = "A combination lock with a secret code. ";
        if(locked){
            result += "It is currently locked";
        } else {
            result += "It is currently open";
        }
        return result;                
    }
}
```

Now how do we use this lock? Let's add one more method that asks a user for 3 numbers and then tries to unlock it.

```
public void promptUser(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter 3 digits for your code.");

    int a = keyboard.nextInt();
    int b = keyboard.nextInt();
    int c = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Clockwise " + num1 + "- Counter-Clockwise " + 
                       num2 + "- Clockwise " + num3);

    unlock(a,b,c);
}
```

Now let's write a main method to try out our lock:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CombinationLock lock = new CombinationLock(3,5,2);
    System.out.println(lock);
    lock.promptUser();
    System.out.println(lock);
}


A combination lock with a secret code.
It is currently locked
Please enter 3 digits for your code.
3
5
2

You try turning Clockwise 3- Counter-Clockwise 5- Clockwise 2
A combination lock with a secret code.
It is currently open
```

Comment: After your comment clarifying what was expected.Ravi's answer is better.

Answer (score -1):

Should change your code to below:

```
public String toString(){

    return "Clockwise " + num1 + "- Counter-Clockwise " + num2 + "- Clockwise " + num3;

  }

CombinationLock(int a, int b, int c){

    num1 = a;
    num2 = b;
    num3 = c;

    open = true;
}
```

Then in your main method do following :

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter 3 digits for your code.");

int a = keyboard.nextInt();
int b = keyboard.nextInt();
int c = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.close();

CombinationLock cl = new CombinationLock(a,b,c);
System.out.println(cl);
```

**[DEMO](https://ideone.com/6gQtBv)**

Comment: im not the downvoter but why are you printing the memory adress of cl?

Comment: then tell me how are you going to use `toString` ?

Comment: System.out.println(cl.toString);

Comment: No need to write explicitly. It works same without writing explicitly. You can try.

Comment: I wanted to do that but I was explicitly asked to use certain methods. But you are right this is probably the smarter way of doing it.

Comment: I have provided demo link... you can see. If post was helpful then upvote otherwise do let me know.. if any correction required

Comment: @jobethbillien Ravi is right and you can also read it in the official JavaDoc of the println method which states `This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value` and String.valueOf(Object) JavaDoc states clearly that it returns `if the argument is null then a string equal to "null"otherwise, the value of
obj.toString() is returned.` So yes. calling System.out.println(Object) will invoke the objects toString method.

Comment: @Ravi just realized there is a typo in your answer: The toString prints num1 twice instead num2.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected